# Sorted directory listing using pattern regexp matching

Tags: c++, regex, sorting, boost, filesystems

I am guilty of using the following code snippet using boost-filesystem and boost-regexp to get the absolute path+filenames from a directory entered as argument.

Where `input_dir` is the variable holding the argument from the command line denoting the name of the directory to be traversed,

```
  string dir_abs_name = "./" + input_dir;
  string file_abs_name;
  path current_dir(dir_abs_name);
  boost::regex pattern("m.*"); // list all files starting with m

  for (directory_iterator iter(current_dir),end; iter!=end; ++iter) {
    string name = iter->path().leaf();
    if (regex_match(name, pattern)) {
      file_abs_name = dir_abs_name + name;
      input_file = str_to_char(file_abs_name); // my own function that converts string to char* (needed that for another method later on in the code)

      std::cout << "--> considering file " << input_file << "... \n";
    }
  }
```

Now I'm facing a problem that the listing isn't alphabetical. I get random matches instead of them being in any particular order. Is there a way to enforce that alphabetical order?

Thanks.

EDIT: It's worth a mention that in the program I am sometimes working on only a subset of the entire file-list in the dir. I do this when I pass an argument to make a selection of, let's say just 4 files out of 1000 in the directory. It is possible to sort them after the retrieval of the list.. but the retrieval still remains random.

Answer (score 3):

Why not cache results in say an (std::vector), sort the vector, then iterate over the sorted vector to perform your processing?

For example:

```
string dir_abs_name = "./" + input_dir;
string file_abs_name;   
path current_dir(dir_abs_name);   
boost::regex pattern("m.*"); // list all files starting with m
std::vector<std::string> accumulator;
for (directory_iterator iter(current_dir),end; iter!=end; ++iter) {     
    string name = iter->path().leaf();
    if (regex_match(name, pattern)) {
       file_abs_name = dir_abs_name + name; 
       accumulator.push_back(file_abs_name);
    }   
}
std::sort(accumulator.begin(), accumulator.end());
std::vector<std::string>::iterator iter;
for (iter = accumulator.begin(); iter != accumulator.end(); ++iter) {
    char* input_file = str_to_char(*iter); // my own function that converts string to char* (needed that for another method later on in the code)                            
    std::cout << "--> considering file " << input_file << "... \n"; 
}
```

Comment: This would solve it, yes, but I was looking for a way to regexp-match them in order.
In the program, I am sometimes working on only a subset of the entire file-list. I do this when I pass an argument to make a selection of, let's say just 4 files out of 1000 in the directory. Even though your modification would make them sorted.. they themselves would still be randomly selected (for example; they would still be 12, 22, 84, and 96 rather than being 1,2,3,4).

Comment: I'd suggest using an `std::set` rather than an `std::vector` since a set is always ordered. Just insert into the set and later iterate on it

Comment: Aarohi, so the way I understand the problem is you now need to be able to select the first (alphabetically) n files from a directory or set of directories. If that is the case, you need to either: 1 - change the way you iterate the file system.  2 - Still use the process above, but select the first four from the vector after sorting.  Obviously, the second solution requires indexing all files in the input set - therefore maybe a smarter person could help you with solution 1.